# Is there a way to declare a key attribute in ADT without the use of SE24?

Tags: workflow, abap, abap-adt

When using the interface `IF_WORKFLOW` design a Business Object to be used in SAP Workflow, one can declare a key attribute using SE24. This helps when using SWUE to raise business events and test workflows.

[image: flag for key attribute in SE24]

Is there a way to declare and display this flag for a key attribute using ADT? The data declaration in the public section looks exactly the same as for a regular attribute.

[image]

I tried opening the class in ADT and expected there to be some kind of representation of the flag.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Unfortunately, it is not possible to display / define it in Eclipse. This functionality is specific to the `SE24` **Class Builder**, where the classes, which are implementing **IF_WORKFLOW** interface are recognized as workflow-enabled and an additional column `Key Attributes` on the Attributes tab is shown.

Please note, that for some SAP releases there was a bug, where the Attributes of Business- or Workflow-Classes were lost if editing the class in source-based mode or editing some source text sections directly (which was related to editing in Eclipse also).
Check the SAP-Note [2400131](https://me.sap.com/notes/2400131) for further details.

Comment: Thank your for your response. Seems like this is intended behaviour. Do you happen to know why there is no indicator in source based editor/ADT?

Comment: I do not know for sure but suppose because it is some really special functionality concerned with only one sap component (workflow) and limited to one interface; such a design decision was taken in the past and they tweaked the class editor tool for this. But it may make no sense to carry it always further and rather leave as a technical debt - in any case who needs it can always mark key attributes in the class editor.